# After effects: Adding visual callouts of currently playing audio files with a source text script

Tags: after-effects, audio, after-effects-expressions

I'm working on a short film, and I've got AE CS 6 as my editor. I have a friend who is an audio engineer, who will perform the Protools final audio mixing and editing. I've got some sound effects in my AE file that I like, and I'd love a good way to add visual text callouts about which audio file is currently playing. That way, he can save time by not having to search thru my big shared audio library to find the exact sound (.wav) that's currently playing.
  It seems like it would be a text layer with an expression on the Source text, and a for loop, but I can't imagine how to write the expression.
  I hope this makes sense.
Thanks in advance!
Geoff

Answer (score 1):

You are making your and your friend's job much harder than it would have to be. Try exporting an xml (if it's possible to read audio-xlms in protools) or, which would be much easier, your friend switches over to audition. That way you can simply load your audio-timeline into audition and it's all there. Trying to recreate your mix is a terrible idea as you will risk damaging the synced audio of dialogue etc.
Alternatively, if none of that works, assign each audio channel a role (such as vox, ambient, wind, punches, etc.) and export each track on its own. He could then import every track which will be in sync just the way you had it and slice the individual tracks up if he wants to.